# DBpedia Graph Extraction

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I have `topics θ` described by `[patient, drug, hospital, health,professional]`
I want to build link between them and get parent and child category for each topic. How can I do this? 
I don't understand the structure of the "semantic web," so even pseudo-code would help me.

Comment: I think my request should look like this -                                                                                 dbpedia:Nokia dcterms:subject category:Finnish_brands
category:Finnish_brands skos:broader category:Brands_by_country            
But I don't know how to apply this to my case.

Comment: "I don't understand the structure of the semantic web" - you should try to understand this first. Please read an RDF tutorial and think about graphs with nodes and edges.

Comment: Next, you have to find the resources that represent your topic, i.e. find classes or as you mentioned, DBpedia (Wikipedia) categories for you topics. I don't think you'll find a category or class for patient, but note, not everything exists in DBpedia.

Comment: You might start with some basics, like [_Understanding Data_](https://www.slideshare.net/kidehen/understanding-29894555).

Comment: I am at a loss as to how "Nokia" and "Finnish brands" play into your "[patient, drug, hospital, health,professional]" data...